# Tablets missing in supported device of the Google Play developer console

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, tablet

After I've uploaded my app on **Play Store**, only 3223 devices on 7730 are supported. 
It seems that **tablets** can't see my app on the Play Store searches.
I've added screenshot for 7' and 10' tablet too.

In Android Manifest I've declared:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="it.mypackage.com"
android:versionCode="45"
android:versionName="1.01" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />

<!-- support for tablets -->
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: To short informations. Post your whole AndroidManifest. Maybe some permissions disabled some Tablets...

Comment: Get rid of `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />`, as there is no such permission in standard Android. I doubt that it will help with this problem, but having it is not helping your app. Also note that `android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS` is "not for use by third-party applications" according to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS).

Comment: so when android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS will be used ?

Comment: It's only for Android-Permission itself. Or System-Signed Applications like Samsungs or HTC Bloadware... But you can't use it.

Comment: tried to upload the new .apk, but nothing to do... again 3223 devices supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you set "uses-feature" your app will not show in play store for devices that don't have the request hardware.

For example not all tablets have flash, so your app will not be visible for those tablets.

You need to add for each "uses-feature" the attribute "required" and set it to false.

You can read about it in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html